# Find folders in a directory, then list them as options in bash script

Tags: arrays, bash

I am writing a script in order to perform a series of operations with the development sites I have in my local machine. The idea is to list all folders (websites) in "/var/www/" and let the user choose one to perform subsequent operations. I found some inspiration for this script [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1705/how-can-i-create-a-select-menu-in-a-shell-script).

I am just beginning to learn bash, so do expect profanities in the code:

This is where I am stuck:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www
options=( $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%P\n') )
options[$[${#options[@]}+1]]="type a new site"

title="Website developing script"
prompt="Choose the site:"

echo "$title"
PS3="$prompt "
select opt in "${options[@]}" "Quit"; do 

    case "$REPLY" in
        # so far so good, all folders are properly listed as options            

        # the answer, I guess, is placing a loop here in order to change this
        # example line into a list of options, but I can't figure out how
        1 ) echo "You picked $opt which is option $REPLY";;    

    $(( ${#options[@]}+1 )) ) echo "Exiting"; break;;
    *) echo "Invalid option. Try another one.";continue;;

    esac

done
```

Any hints are most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `$[]` for arithmetic is deprecated. Use `$(())` instead. However, an array subscript is already an arithmetic context, so: `options[${#options[@]}+1]="type a new site"`, **but** you can append to an array without needing to increment an index, so: `options+=("type a new site")`

Answer (score 0):

Define function(s) to handle each case. Instead of those echo statements in switch cases, call the appropriate functions with all required arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest cases to handle "Quit" and "Type a new site" and a general case for performing all the actions on any selected directory.

The following is slightly hackish.

Untested.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www
options=( $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%P\n') )
lastdirindex=${#options[@]}

saveIFS=$IFS
IFS='|'
pattern="^(${options[*]})$" # create a regex that looks like: ^(dir1|dir2|dir3)$
IFS=$saveIFS

options+=("type a new site")
newindex=${#options[@]}
options+=("Quit")
quitindex=${#options[@]}

processchoice () { echo "Do stuff with choice $1 here"; }

title="Website developing script"
prompt="Choose the site:"

echo "$title"
PS3="$prompt "

select opt in "${options[@]}"; do 
    case $([[ $REPLY =~ $pattern ]] && echo 1 || echo "$REPLY") in
        1          )  echo "You picked $opt which is option $REPLY"; processchoice "$REPLY";;
        $newindex  )  read -r -p "Enter a new site" newsite; processchoice "$newsite";;
        $quitindex )  echo "Exiting"; break;;
        *          )  echo "Invalid option. Try another one."; continue;;
    esac
done
```